# Terminal is stuck on python manage.py makemigrations and runserver

Tags: python, django, mongodb, django-rest-framework, terminal

I am using Pycharm for django development, after adding some models to the models.py the terminal is stuck at python manage.py makemigrations command, runserver doesn't work also.

The terminal is freezing.

It was working perfectly, it did not work after the modification in models.py, I tried to delete the migration files but it didn't work, restart the computer didn't help.
Look at the pictures please.

Any ideas?

Thanks a lot

[makemigrations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gv1px.png)
[runserver](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AZxQ3.png)

Comment: When I've run into this in the past, it has been a connection hanging somewhere; make sure you can connect to your database (`python manage.py dbshell`, or use `telnet` to try to connect to the server and port), any LDAP servers you may be using, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The same situation happened to me and I looked deeper at the models I had changed.

I just commented the fields i didn't want anymore, not removed, that was the problem. Try removing.

Maybe the command "python manage.py makemigrations" already ran and you just need to do a "python manage.py migrate".